When starting a WinUI3 app I get asked to install or update Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.0 but it is already installed
I get this error message when I try to start my WinUI 3 apps from Visual Studio:

But I already installed the newest .net v8.0.8. I also tried to install the specified v8.0.0 version but it did not help either. The installed runtimes on my PC:

My apps are WindowsAppSDKSelfContained with the following settings in the .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86;win-x64;win-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PublishProfile>win-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
    <UseRidGraph>true</UseRidGraph>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>

    <WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
    <WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
</PropertyGroup>

But interestingly when I start the .exe from the output folder it runs perfectly without this issue for one winui3 app but the other app has the same issue even when started from the .exe file. Both have the same settings in the .csproj files.

Are you having this issue from the start? or during the development? How about if you create a plain non-packaged, self-contained WinUI 3 app?

Could you please tell us what version of the Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK you're using?

@AndrewKeepCoding This issue appeared like a week ago. When I create another non-packaged, self-contained WinUI 3 app with the same settings in the .csproj it works fine without this error.

@Jeaninez-MSFT I was using an older version (1.4.230913002) when this issue appeared so I tried to update it to 1.6.240829007 version but the issue still persist.
It may also worth to mention that if I add the <SelfContained>true </SelfContained> tag in the .csproj then the issue is gone. But I do not plan to use this option because I want the users to install the runtime I do not want to deliver it.

Have you tried deleting the bin folder, obj folder and restart VS?

@AndrewKeepCoding Yes, I already tried cleaning the project and deleting the bin and obj folders as well. Did not help unfortunately.

I'd try unloading and reloading the project and if that doesn't help compare each file (*.sln, *.csproj, *.json, *.pubxml, etc...) with a working project. I also would look for information about the error message "You must install or update...".

I think I found the issue. The root cause of the problem was a Windows App SDK versioning mismatch. I started to use another WinUI project that used a newer version of the SDK and when I installed it, it broke my previous WinUI app somehow. After I updated the Windows App SDK nuget package to a newer version that the older project used, I could start my old winui app again.

The root cause of the problem was probably a Windows App SDK versioning mismatch. Especially when developing unpackaged apps, the version of the Windows App SDK installed on the PC has to match exactly the version of the Windows App SDK NuGet package of the WinUI project, otherwise issues arise.
After I updated to a newer version of that NuGet package the issue got resolved.
